# How to retrieve data into selenium java script using Angular method

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, selenium

I want to retrieve visitor ID from “visitor” or "visitor.VisitorId" . but below code I use to retrieve data but successfully run without any error but I received value is null.

**HTML Code:-**

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li id="visitorView" class="treeview active">
<a>
<ul id="visitorViewMenu" class="treeview-menu menu-open" style="display: block;">
<!-- ngRepeat: visitor in Visitors -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="visitor in Visitors" style="">
<a id="visitor.VisitorId" class="ng-binding" ng-click="select(visitor)">
<countryflag class="flagimg ng-isolate-scope" visitor="visitor">
<span class="chattabname"/>
A 
<span class="timmer1 pull-right" runtimer="{"VisitorID":"c2c45b4d-5077-492f-afd6-88ab3bba99cd","Name":"A","StartTime":"2016-09-09 10:33:21","WidgetId":"7fcf22c6-4a9d-4701-9865-b8a85d597862","ConnectionId":"edc7d72b-8217-4961-81ff-f4ef4138bc3b","TimeZone":"Asia/Colombo","CountryCode":"lk","VisitorName":null,"Department":null,"CompanyId":"a4afbd8b-1de9-49d9-8fe6-4ec8119f4bb8"}">
</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: visitor in Visitors -->
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="treeview">
<li class="treeview">
</ul>
```

**Selenium Code:-**

```
**1st method :-** 
    WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[ng-click='select(visitor)']"));

**2nd method :-** 
    WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id='visitor.VisitorId']"));

**Output**  
    System.out.println("+++-- "+cityField.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`getText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--) which will return `innerText` of the `<a>` element as below :-

```
WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.id("visitor.VisitorId"));
System.out.println("+++-- "  + cityField.getText());
```

Or if you want to get `span` element where `visitorId` present in `runtimer` attribute value, you should locate `span` element and get `runtimer` attribute value as :-

```
WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id = 'visitor.VisitorId'] span.timmer1"));
String runtimeData = cityField.getAttribute("runtimer");

//Now do some programming stuff to retrieve visitor id
```

`runtimer` attribute data looks like in `json` format, so you can retrieve any data after converting in into [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) by passing their `key` as below :-

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static Object getValue(String data, String key) throws JSONException {
      JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(data);
       return jObject.get(key);
}


String visitorID = (String) getValue(runtimeData, "VisitorID");
System.out.println(visitorID);
```

**Output** :-

> c2c45b4d-5077-492f-afd6-88ab3bba99cd

As OP suggested, we can use `split()` function as well to retrieve data as :-

```
String[] splitS = runtimeData.split(","); 

for(int i =0; i < splitS.length; i++) 
{ 
  System.out.println("splitS" + splitS[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I tried your cityField.getAttribute("runtimer"); last updated Answer. it is working and i used split function to split data. Here my code user    `String[] splitS = runtimeData.split(",");
      for(int i =0; i < splitS.length; i++)
      {
       System.out.println("splitS"+splitS[i]);
      }`  if you can modify your answer using this code i hope it would be really help for beginners.

Comment: Yeah, sure and thanks for your suggestion as well..:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the value you are looking for is in the `runtimer` attribute that located in descendant element of `id="visitor.VisitorId"`, you need to put that in `getAttribute()` method

```
WebElement cityField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#visitor.VisitorId > .timmer1"));
String attributeData = cityField.getAttribute("runtimer");
String visitorId = attributeData.split(",");
System.out.println("+++-- " + visitorId);
```

Output: `+++-- "VisitorID":"c2c45b4d-5077-492f-afd6-88ab3bba99cd"`